# How to delete user folders for old user in C:\Documents and Settings in Windows 2003

Tags: windows, user-accounts, user-profiles

I have got an old laptop from a previous employee of my company. Because all the software I need is preconfigured on the laptop I am using the laptop as-is without un-installing or re-installing any of the softwares. The only thing I did is I create another user for myself and I am not using any of the existing user.

But in the `C:\Documents and Settings` folder, I can see the user folders for previous users which contain almost 3 GB of data.

Can I delete all these folders safely? If these folders can not be deleted fully, then what subfolders can be deleted safely? As the user folder generally contains lots of subfolder like: `ApplicationData, LocalSettings, Desktop, StatMenu` etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you do it the "proper Windows way" and use Start -> Run -> lusrmgr.msc to remove the users before actually removing the files.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using any of the files and there's no need to back them up, you can delete the entire user's folder.